# IMS Database connection using Python

Tags: ims-db

I am developing a code to compare the Data between the IMS Database and the feed file generated from a downstream.

How can I connect with IMS Database using Python. Can someone please provide the detailed steps?

Haven't tried anything from my side.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the IMS Universal Drivers. You could connect to an IMS Database using JDBC, if you want to write your programs in Python you can use for example jpype to achieve this.

This does however **require** a datastore/IMS Connect to be configured for the system which you're trying to access since IMS Connect will be the way distributed applications access to system.

Heres a Java sample application:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/15.1.0?topic=driver-sample-application-ims-universal-jdbc

Read more at:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/15.1.0?topic=drivers-ims-universal-overview